# How to test if a host ip is accessible or not in Linux, using ARP REQUEST/REPLY packages?

Tags: linux, arp

How to test if a host ip is accessible or not in Linux, using ARP REQUEST/REPLY packages ?

Does anyone know the command or have a program in C++/C that does that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arping` may do the magic for you? http://linux.die.net/man/8/arping

The arping utility performs an action similar to ping command, but at the Ethernet layer. You can send ARP REQUEST to a neighbor host / computers.